# Understanding noun+で見える

Tags: grammar, particles

> 気がつけば、目の前にそれはいた。 　 シンはぞっと戦慄を覚える。 　 同じ顔だった。 　
> 遠縁だという青年の顔を、シンは知らないから自分の顔**で見えた**のかもしれないし、本当にそれほど似ていたのかもしれない。フレデリカが何度も重ねてしまうほどに。
>
> 86─エイティシックス─Ep.3 ─ラン・スルー・ザ・バトルフロント─〈下〉

安里アサト

[image]

Could you please explain the bold で? Given the meaning is that シン’s face looks pretty like that of the 青年, shouldn’t we use に見えた here?

Answer (score 3):

You are right in that に would be more normal. It is an idiosyncratic choice of the author to use で, which means *by, with* here.

に見えた would just mean *the face looked **like** his own*. で見えた gives a nuance that *the visual impression given by the face **was replaced by his own***, i.e., シン was in the state of looking at a mirror when he saw the guy.

---

The closest (more common) usage of で would be "(の声)**で**再生される". For example

- 自分の世代は、「僕ドラえもん」は大山のぶ代で再生される。
- For those of my generation, 僕ドラえもん is played with/by/in the voice of Nobuyo Ohyama

(Note: Oyama is the original voice actress of Doraemon, who was replaced quite a while ago. The phrase is characteristic of Doraemon, just like オッスおら悟空 for Goku of Dragonball.).

FYI: A related word (kind of internet slang) is [脳内再生](https://dic.nicovideo.jp/a/%E8%84%B3%E5%86%85%E5%86%8D%E7%94%9F).

Comment: Idiosyncratic is a nice way to put it. Besides their choice of particles, I don’t like the way this author uses punctuation. 青年の顔を goes with 知らない, not 見えた. Why do they have to put a comma there? It should be moved to after 知らないから. If they insist on a comma there, then the particle for 青年の顔 should be changed to が so it matches 見えた as well as 似ていた. For me, it’s simply poor writing.